# Can you identify this mystery plant? possibly mint?

Tags: identification, mint, outdoor, edible, poisons

I got this creeping plant the other day on clearance at a local walmart under the pretense that it was part of the mint family. It smells minty but it has no identification on it. I was hoping that someone could help me identify this. I am just confused and figured I should ask people who are seasoned in the hobby :) link is to multiple photos of said plant

[image]
[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: We need better pictures - the stem is not visible in the photo where you;re holding that bit of foliage so I can't tell if its square or not, and the second photo does not magnify well and again, the stems cannot clearly be seen. Was it in that hanging pot when you bought it?

Comment: Better photos,from which it appears this is not a member of the mint family - was it in the hanging pot when you bought it ,  or did you move it into that from an ordinary pot?